# Pandas concat multiple excel file in folder by pre defined sheets

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I'm trying to concat multiple files in folder with pre defined sheets name (Because each file has some sheets that I don't want to concat) but I got a problem as below. I'm trying to do with below code:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import glob
import io
folder = Path(r'D:\Test\New folder')

for file in folder.glob('*xlsx'):
    sheet_name = ['총','하노이', '호치민', '박닌', '빈증', '동나이', '비엔화', '다낭', '타이응웬',
                  '하이퐁', '호안끼엠', '스타레이크', '하남', '빈푹', '푸미흥', '껀터', '사이공']
    dfs = []
    for x in sheet_name:
        df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=x)
        base_date = df.iloc[0, 10]
        branch = df.iloc[1, 12]
        df.columns = df.iloc[2]
        df = df[3:]
        # Xóa cột NaN
        df = df.loc[:, df.columns.notnull()]
        df_2 = df.iloc[:, 0:4]
        df_3 = df.iloc[:, 4:]
        df = pd.concat([df_2, df_3], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
        df['Base Date'] = base_date
        df['Base Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Base Date'], format='%d-%m-%Y').dt.strftime('%Y%m%d').astype(int)
        df['Branch'] = branch
        dfs.append(df)

    output = pd.concat(dfs, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    print(output)
```

It raised error that said `ValueError: Worksheet named '' not found` (Because in my file may have not sheets that I pre defined). So I tried with below code:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import glob
import io
folder = Path(r'D:\Test\New folder')

for file in folder.glob('*xlsx'):
    sheet_name = ['총','하노이', '호치민', '박닌', '빈증', '동나이', '비엔화', '다낭', '타이응웬',
                  '하이퐁', '호안끼엠', '스타레이크', '하남', '빈푹', '푸미흥', '껀터', '사이공']
    dfs = []
    for x in sheet_name:
        try:
            df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=x)
            base_date = df.iloc[0, 10]
            branch = df.iloc[1, 12]
            df.columns = df.iloc[2]
            df = df[3:]
            # Xóa cột NaN
            df = df.loc[:, df.columns.notnull()]
            df_2 = df.iloc[:, 0:4]
            df_3 = df.iloc[:, 4:]
            df = pd.concat([df_2, df_3], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
            df['Base Date'] = base_date
            df['Base Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Base Date'], format='%d-%m-%Y').dt.strftime('%Y%m%d').astype(int)
            df['Branch'] = branch
            dfs.append(df)
        except ValueError as e:
            pass
    output = pd.concat(dfs, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    print(output)
```

But with this code, it just work for one last file. How can I achieve my goal?
Here is the link for the sample data: https://github.com/hoatranobita/concat

Comment: Because `dfs` is reset to [] within your first for loop, and variable `output` is redefined as `dfs` created from the reset `dfs` based on one file, it will only work on the last file, as `dfs` is reset to [] again when it moves to the next file, untill last file. Check your variables through debugging.

Comment: @PandaKim: Thank for your comment, what should I change in my code?

Comment: You can create `dfs1` as [] above the first loop and then store variable `output` of each file in `dfs1`.

Comment: @PandaKim: I'm sorry but can you edit my code then post it as an answer, I'm not sure I understand it.

Comment: **Your code is not reproducible**, so I cannot create an answer for you. I cannot modify the code because I do not get the same result when I run your code. [I think you should provide a reproducible example if you want to get your code modified on SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Based on the hints, it would also be one way to study the for loop again. If you have the will to solve the problem yourself by spending time on my hints, you can solve the problem easily.

Comment: Here is a brief explanation of the problems with non-reproducible code. The advantage of coding is that everyone can easily run the code and answer questions. However, non-reproducible code forces the answerer to code only in their brain without running it. Even if the code I provide is correct and errors occur, the questioner may not be able to understand where the errors are occurring in the process of applying it. Therefore, I have to participate in all debugging processes. Providing non-reproducible code means that I am essentially doing your work for you, so I cannot provide an answer.

Comment: @PandaKim: It's quite strange that before posting here I run my code and it is reproducible code. Did you try to download my file that I mentioned in my question?

Comment: I have seen the file, but the fact that I have to download the file and create the same environment as you in order to solve your problem means that this is more of me taking over your work than answering your question. Can you not be satisfied with the hints I provided you with the cause? If you have identified the cause but cannot fix the for loop, I don't think this is a problem that can be solved by asking a question. It is a basic for loop. The variable `output` in your code is reset for each file, so you need to create variable to receive and store it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

I think that most problems can be solved by providing reproducible code if the problem is isolated without publishing the entire code. However, since you say that you cannot create it and that it is difficult to reach the answer with hints, I will create it for you this one time.

```
import pandas as pd

url1 = 'https://github.com/hoatranobita/concat/blob/main/20191231%20%EC%98%81%EC%97%85%EC%A0%90%20%EC%8B%A4%EC%A0%81%20%EA%B3%84%EC%82%B0%ED%91%9C_v1.xlsx?raw=ture'
url2 = 'https://github.com/hoatranobita/concat/blob/main/20200630%20%EC%98%81%EC%97%85%EC%A0%90%20%EC%8B%A4%EC%A0%81%20%EA%B3%84%EC%82%B0%ED%91%9C_v1.xlsx?raw=true'
files = [url1, url2] # 두개의 파일 경로명이 담긴 리스트, 본문의 folder.glob('*xlsx') 역할을 한다

dfs1 = [] # 매 파일마다 reset되는 output을 reset되기 전에 저장할 변수

for file in files: # files가 본문의 folder.glob('*xlsx') 역할을 한다
    sheet_name = ['하노이', '호치민'] # minimalize
    dfs = []
    for x in sheet_name:
        try:
            df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=x)
            base_date = df.iloc[0, 10]
            branch = df.iloc[1, 12]
            df.columns = df.iloc[2]
            df = df[3:]
            # Xóa cột NaN
            df = df.loc[:, df.columns.notnull()]
            df_2 = df.iloc[:, 0:4]
            df_3 = df.iloc[:, 4:]
            df = pd.concat([df_2, df_3], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
            df['Base Date'] = base_date
            df['Base Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Base Date'], format='%d-%m-%Y').dt.strftime('%Y%m%d').astype(int)
            df['Branch'] = branch
            dfs.append(df)
        except ValueError as e:
            pass
    output = pd.concat(dfs, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    dfs1.append(output) # output을 dfs1에 저장
out = pd.concat(dfs1) # 저장된 output들을 concat해서 새로운 변수 out으로 지정
```

out

[image]

The variable `output` in your code is reset for each file, so you need to create an object to receive and store it (here, the variable `dfs1`). This will solve the problem.

I think the code inside your for loop should also be improved, but it is not important for the code to work, so I have kept your code as it is.

Comment: Thank you for that, I will try to learn more about for loop :D

Comment: @hoatran Rather than trying to ask questions by including all the code, make a reproducible example. I used your Excel file to make a reproducible example because I was lazy, but even if you didn't, you could have created four example data frames and divided them into two pairs and arranged them in a list. This would have been sufficient to reproduce the mechanism you are trying to do for the other person. In any case, glad that it was resolved.